# How Can I Store the array of objects in DynamoDB

Tags: java, json, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I know how to insert items into DynamoDB when it was in the below type

eg:
    {
    "id" : "10021",
    "AppName" "testingApp"
    }

But I want to insert array of objects like in the below example:

eg:

```
{
"testArray": [
{ "id" : "testID",
  "applicationName" : "Myapp"
},
 {
 "id" : "testID1",
  "applicationName" : "Myapp123"
} ]}
```

If Dynamo DB cannot store above type of JSON data, then can you please suggest  which DB would be better to store this type of input..?

Comment: Have you tried the [`List attribute`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html#DDB-Type-AttributeValue-L)?

Comment: How Can I create a table which can store data in the above format JSON on AWS console

Comment: On AWS console you just need to open the table, click "Create Item" and just copy/paste or type down the JSON object there.

Comment: Yes I tried the same but I don't see it stored the values like expected it to store ( which is the format in the question)

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB can store JSON data , also the data format you wish to insert.
There are two methods which can be used to format the data while inserting into DynamoDB and also while retrieving the DB data into desired JSON method.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/Converter.html
These methods are : `input` and `output`.

I have shared two sample snippets of AWS lambda code to do so, hope this solves your problem.

With the following way you can convert JSON data into DynamoDB supported format and then insert it:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
//setting the region
AWS.config.update({region: 'ap-south-1'});

// Create the DynamoDB service object
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();


const getParams = (updatedTasks)=>{
const params = {
  TableName: 'todo-application',
  Key: {
    "userID" : "anandujjwal13@gmail.com",
  },
  UpdateExpression: "set tasks = :updatedTasks",
   ExpressionAttributeValues:{
        ":updatedTasks":updatedTasks
    },
    ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"
};
return params;
}

const dbQuery =(newTask)=>{
    let updatedTask = AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.input(newTask, true);
    console.log('updated task formatted ',updatedTask);
 let params = getParams(updatedTask);
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
  ddb.update(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
    reject(err);
  } else {
    console.log("Success", data);
    resolve(data.Item)
  }
});
});
}


exports.updateTodoJobsOfAUser = async (event) => {
    const insertObject = [
    {
    statement:'learn Dynamo DB', id: 23
    },
    {
    statement:'Learn Serverless Architecture',id:24 
    }]
    const data = await dbQuery(insertObject);
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    };
    return response;
};
```

With following way you can convert DynamoDB data into JSON format :

```js
const dbQuery =()=>{
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
  ddb.get(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
    reject(err);
  } else {
    console.log("Success", data);
    resolve(data.Item)
  }
});
});
}


exports.getAllTodoJobsOfAUser = async (event) => {
    const data = await dbQuery();
    const formattedData =  AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.output(data, true);
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(formattedData)
    };
    return response;
};
```

Happy to help

Answer (score -1):

try using map attribute inside a list attribute

list gives you an array and map gives you an object of key value pairs

Comment: An example would help the OP to understand what you mean.